# copy image from one file to folder python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using conda interface in python-3.6 and it is not saving images to the specified path. What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from shutil import copyfile

dire=r'C:\Users\JZ\Desktop\books'
fnames = [r'C:\Users\JZ\Desktop\DLIMAGES\WarningsNegative.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(0, 1665)]
gnames=['Warnings.{}'.format(i) for i in range(0, 1665)]

for each in range(0,1665):
    path=os.path.join(dire,gnames[each])


    print('dst=', path)
    im=Image.open(fnames[each])
    temp=im.copy()
    #gene=str(path).replace("\\","/")
    with open(path,'wb') as newline:
         temp.save(newline,"JPEG")
```

Comment: What *is* it doing, rather? Is there an error? Does it save in a wrong place? Does it shutdown your computer, or insult your mother? The description of what it does do is much more valuable than the description of what it doesn't do :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @Amadan It is able to print the destination file where it has to save image (the path). But it is not saving the image to the folder that it is intended to save to ,the folder is blank. This is happening when I don't include (with open) and when I am including it, it is showing permission denied.

Comment: What is the path? Is it correct? Do you have permissions to write there?

Comment: @Amadan yes the path it is printing is dst= C:\Users\JZ\Desktop\books\Warnings.92 and I think I have windows system that is why there is a problem in slashes and its not inputting it as address

Comment: @Amadan ... Can't I set the permissions by using 'wb'

Comment: No. `wb` means you're (trying to) opening the file for _writing_ in _binary mode_. It has nothing to do with permissions.